# ASP.NET Core MVC : @Html.DropDownList on change pass ViewBag as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

I am creating an ASP.NET Core MVC application. I have a `@Html.DropDownList` and in the on change function, I want to pass as parameter a `ViewBag` value

```
 @Html.DropDownList("PageSize", new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, int> { { "10", 10 }, { "20", 20 }, { "30", 30 }, { "40", 40 }, { "50", 50 }, { "100", 100 } }, "Key", "Value", Convert.ToString(ViewBag.PageSize)), new { id = "SearchPageSize", style = "width: 100px;", @onchange = "AAA(ViewBag.CurrentSort)" })
```

The function `AAA` is never called, and I get this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ViewBag is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

It does not like how I am passing the parameter `ViewBag.CurrentSort`

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe string.Format("AAA({0})", @ViewBag.CurrentSort)

Comment: I doesnt even load the page... it has a page error. you mean  @onchange = string.Format("AAA({0})", @ViewBag.CurrentSort) ? thanks

Comment: Yes but I didn't test it. I personally wouldn't do it that way. Use jQuery .on with the action 'change' and place the ViewBag item in a hidden input. Then you can retrieve the hidden input and get the value.

Comment: `onchange = "AAA(@ViewBag.CurrentSort);"`, you may need to enclose the param in quotes.  Check the html output in the source.

Comment: Got the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: the value is @ViewBag.CurrentSort, take it as string... thanks..

Comment: I do an alert(value) and shows @ViewBag.CurrentSort instead of the value

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the context, which is c#.
Since the property being set is from the c# side, no `@` is required.
To get the quotes around the parameter, use `string.Format`.

```
onchange=string.Format("AAA('{0}')", ViewBag.CurrentSort)
```

Comment: The page does not load.... it has a jquery error.. thanks